# MYSQL: How to update unique random number to existing rows

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysqldbcompare

It's been my first question to this website, I'm sorry if I used any wrong keywords. I have been with one problem from quite a few days.

The Problem is, I have a MYSQL table named property where I wanted to add a ref number which will be a unique 6 digit non incremental number so I alter the table to add a new column named `property_ref` which has default value as 1.

```
ALTER TABLE property ADD uniqueIdentifier INT DEFAULT (1) ;
```

Then I write a script to first generate a number then checking it to db if exist or not and If not exist then update the row with the random number

Here is the snippet I tried,

```
with cte as (
select subIdentifier, id from (
    SELECT id, LPAD(FLOOR(RAND() * (999999 - 100000) + 100000), 6, 0) AS subIdentifier
    FROM property as p1
    WHERE "subIdentifier" NOT IN (SELECT uniqueIdentifier FROM property as p2) 
) as innerTable group by subIdentifier
)
UPDATE property SET uniqueIdentifier =  (
  select subIdentifier from cte as c where c.id = property.id 
) where property.id != ''
```

this query returns a set of record for almost all the rows but I have a table of entries of total 20000,
but this query fills up for ~19000 and rest of the rows are null.

here is a current output
[current result picture]

[image: 1]

If anyone can help, I am extremely thanks for that.

Thanks

Comment: I wonder if you are getting null values because it is generating the same value twice; in that case your update would not execute. If you run your update script multiple times, are the same rows always blank?

Comment: yeah, you got that right. The error is in the generating the random number. it's not unique for all the records

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to randomly generate unique numbers that do not exist in the table, I would try the approach of randomly generating numbers using the ID column as a seed; as long as the ID number is unique, the new number will be unique as well. This is not technically fully "random" but it may be sufficient for your needs.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iqMPDK8AmdvAoTbon1Yn6J/1

```
update Property set 
UniqueIdentifier =   round(rand(id)*1000000)
where UniqueIdentifier is null

SELECT id,  round(rand(id)*1000000) as UniqueIdentifier FROM test;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, You got my key! Anyways, I cannot upvote your message as I don't have much reputation but extremely thanks :)

Comment: no problem; glad it's working for you! I think you can mark the answer as Accepted which will keep this question off of the "unanswered questions" list.